# iterator is pointing to first element after a "find_if" match, why?

Tags: c++

I'm teaching myself c++ right now so I'm pretty new. One of the problem questions in the book I am learning from asks for a binary predicate that compares 2 strings. Below I've copied what I've written. I'm certain this is one of those really simple solutions, but I can't figure it out myself. Basically, my error is in the if statement. When there is a match, it always prints out the first element instead of the element where there was a match. Can you help explain why that is? What am I doing wrong? Also, as a newbie, I'd appreciate it if you see any 'ugly code' and can identify what you would write differently so that I can clean it up. Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//my comparison predicate starts here

struct comparison{
    string deststring1;
    string deststring2;

comparison (const string& whattheyenter){
    deststring1.resize(whattheyenter.size());
    transform(whattheyenter.begin(),whattheyenter.end(),deststring1.begin(),tolower);
    }

bool operator () (const string& string2) {
    deststring2.resize(string2.size());
    transform(string2.begin(),string2.end(),deststring2.begin(),tolower);
    return (deststring1<deststring2);
    }
};


  //program begins here

int main(){
    string comparethisstring;

    cout<<"enter string to compare: "<<endl;
    cin>>comparethisstring;

    vector<string> listofstrings;

    listofstrings.push_back("my fiRst string");
    listofstrings.push_back("mY sEcond striNg");
    listofstrings.push_back("My ThIrD StRiNg");

    auto ielement = find_if(listofstrings.begin(),listofstrings.end(),comparison(comparethisstring));

    if (ielement!=listofstrings.end()){
          // when there is a match this always prints "my fiRst string" instead of 
          // pointing to the element where the match is.
        cout<<"matched:" <<*ielement; 
    }
    else {
        cout<<"no match found!";
    }

return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Just wanted to say the issue was that first, I used a less than operator, which is no use for comparing equality. Second, I used cin instead of getline. As a result when I typed in "my first string" cin only assigned "my" to comparethisstring. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: `find_if` stops when `deststring1<deststring2` is true, what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize I used a less than operator. That explains it. I'm trying to compare 2 strings regardless of case

Comment: Most likely, you mean to use a predicate which tests for "equality". (Whatever you define that to mean.)

Comment: I changed the less than operator to an == operator but it's showing nothing matches

Comment: @Chowza: Well if you want case insensitive, `'a' != 'A'`. What are you doing with the case insensitiveity? If you are doing this for text the user enters you probably need to use some platform specific API that respects the user's locale settings.

Comment: Regarding "ugly code": This code looks okay and isn't particularly "ugly", but putting in a space between a right parenthesis and an open curly bracket would make the code easier to read (for example, `int main() { ` instead of `int main(){`).  You should also put spaces before and after binary operators, such as `a == b` instead of `a==b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_if` finds the first element for which the predict is `true`.  Your predict is "is it earlier, alphabetically, than `comparethisstring`.  You probably want to return true if and only if you equal `comparethisstring` (or `deststring1==deststring2`).

I would also advise making `deststring2` a variable local to the `operator()` method.

Comment: when I change the return to (deststring1==deststring2) I get "no match found" when I type anything in the variable comparethisstring

Comment: Maybe nothing matches.  You might want to print out `std::cout << "[" <<  comparethisstring << "]\n";` (with the `[]` so you know where the string starts and ends), and do the same with the contents of your `listofstrings`.  As a guess, you have some whitespace in `comparethisstring`.

Comment: okay you've identified the issue. For some reason when I typed a phrase my first string, it didn't get assigned to the variable comparethisstring. when I cout<<comparethisstring, all that shows up is 'my' even though I clearly typed 'my first string'. Is cin>> supposed to function like that? I.e. is it supposed to assign variable comparethisstring to 'my first string' or simply 'my'

Comment: You asked for a string.  It gave you a string.  If you want to read a line, try `std::getline` -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/